# How to Store ArrayList data in OpenOffice calc Spreadsheet using JAVA

Tags: java, c#

I have created ArrayList which contains directory structure (Folder Structure) of E - drive content.
    I want to store directory structure Path in OpenOffice calc spreadsheet using JAVA

Thanks
Manoj

Answer (score 0):

They way I would approach this would be to write your data to a csv (comma separated value) file, and then open that with OpenOffice. CSV is a pretty easy file format to write to. Every line is a row, and each entry in the row is separated by a comma. In OpenOffice you will be able to open the CSV and save it as an OpenOffice spreadsheet.

Here is a code example from a CVS writer library: https://www.csvreader.com/java_csv_samples.php

Comment: I got directory structure in CSV file. but want to save it as a .ods. Having trouble while saving it as a .ods files.